# How can I test whether two strings are rotations of each other?

Tags: java, string

Suppose there is a string `abc` and given rotational strings like `abc`, `bca` ,`cab`(i.e 3 possible rotational strings are possible) similarly i need a method that should take two string as input and tell whether those two follow under this category or not.
I thought of the following:

given string `abc`

string length =3

created a big array `abcbcacab`

and check using contains.

in this solution i have problems

as wrong input also get passed i.e "cbc"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution:

Test string length (after rotation, the string-length would still be the same).
Concatenate the string to itself (either works) and test wether the result contains the other one.

If both tests passed, the two strings are rotations of each other.